# Populate html table using multiple jinja dictionary

Tags: python, html, dictionary

Greeting, I want to populate a HTML table using multiple jinja dictionary reference but doing it like my code below will create duplication instead because of the for loop inside a for loop, how can I fix this, is there any front-end way, or I have to change my function in `view.py`?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

view.py

```
for employee_id in get_employee_id_list:
        get_employee_data = WorkOrder.objects.filter(assign_to=employee_id)
        total_task = get_employee_data.__len__()
        total_employee_task_list.append(total_task)

context = {
        "employee_list": get_employee_id_list,
        "total_employee_task_list": total_employee_task_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'report.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
{% for employee in employee_list %}
{% for total in total_employee_task_list %}
    <tr>   
        <td>{{ employee.official_name }}</td>  
        <td>{{ total }}</td>        
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: What do the two dictionaries look like? It seems like you should combine the total's from your task list into your employee list. As a general rule of thumb, you should try and keep as much logic inside your view.py as you can. Logic in templates is slow and violates separation of concerns (logic belongs in the view, UI belongs in the template)

Comment: you should add ```total count``` in employee_list.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the input, i thought so too, but im not sure how to do it, hope you guys can help figure it out

Comment: and I've updated my code thanks